# I am not able to access the method 'refreshPropertyPane' to refresh the web part properties pane

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

As I am following the tutorial ([Use cascading dropdowns in web part properties](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-cascading-dropdowns-in-web-part-properties))  for learning the sharepoint framework. I did everything as mentioned in the article, but I am not able to access the method "refreshPropertyPane()". Please find the below where i am calling this method. By using this method I want to refresh the web part property pane after getting list of options from API.
Please find the below code :

```
export default class ListItemsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IListItemsWebPartProps> { 
protected onPropertyPaneConfigurationStart(): void {
this.listsDropdownDisabled = !this.lists;
this.itemsDropdownDisabled = !this.properties.listName || !this.items;

if (this.lists) {
  return;
}

this.context.statusRenderer.displayLoadingIndicator(this.domElement, 'options');

this.loadLists()
  .then((listOptions: IDropdownOption[]): Promise<IDropdownOption[]> => {
    this.lists = listOptions;
    this.listsDropdownDisabled = false;
    this.refreshPropertyPane();// ==> I am not able to access method.
    return this.loadItems();
  })
  .then((itemOptions: IDropdownOption[]): void => {
    this.items = itemOptions;
    this.itemsDropdownDisabled = !this.properties.listName;
    this.refreshPropertyPane();
    this.context.statusRenderer.clearLoadingIndicator(this.domElement);
    this.render();
  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the [release note for RC0](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-RC0) it states:

> **BaseClientSideWebPart**
>   ...
>
> - Removed refreshPropertyPane (still on context object)
>
> ...
>   **IWebPartContext**
>   ...
>
> - Moved isPropertyPaneRenderedByWebPart, openPropertyPane, refreshPropertyPane to IPropertyPaneAccessor
>
> ...

so use:

```
this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
```